# Error entering data into web page with Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to enter data into a web page field.
There are 2 data entry fields on the web page.
I entered data in the first section.
However, I cannot enter data in the other field.

Information you need to review the site :

Site : http://splan.byethost7.com/mesaj_yaz.php?fno=1&kip=yeni

user :kurucu password :a11111

I entered the data in the "BAŞLIK" field.
However I am unable to write data to the field named "İÇERİK"

I want to enter data in this field using an Excel macro. But I can't enter data using the code:

```
  Sub deneme()
    Dim URL As String
    On Error Resume Next
    URL = "http://splan.byethost7.com/mesaj_yaz.php?fno=1&kip=yeni"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = 1

    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).row
        If Cells(i, 1) <> Empty Then
            ie.navigate URL

            Call bekle



  ie.Document.getElementById("mesaj_icerik").Value = "TEST"

  ie.document.getElementsByName("mesaj_baslik").Item(0).Value = Cells(i, 1)

 'IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("submitButton")(0).Click

              Call bekle

        End If
    Next i
   ' IE.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub

Sub bekle()
    With ie
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no such thing as `ie.document.getElementsid`. The method you're looking for is probably `ie.document.getElementByID()`. This method returns one single item and not a collection of items, so no need to refer to `.item(0)`.

Comment: Also from what I can see in the HTML snippet you provided, "mesaj_baslik" is a name of a Class and not the Name attribute of some element. So maybe you should be using  `ie.document.getElementsByClassName("formlar_mesajyaz")` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments, there are several issues with your code, although the overall effort is good.

Firstly, this `ie.document.getElementsid("mesaj_baslik")` is not a valid method. If what you want is to access a single HTML element with a unique ID, then the method you need to use is `ie.Document.getElementById("the element's ID")`.

Assuming that what I wrote above is what you were trying to achieve, you have to keep in mind that the `.getElementById()` method, returns only one single element.

So this `ie.Document.getElementById("the element's ID").item(0)` would give you an error saying:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Even if all the aforementioned mistakes were corrected, I still don't see any elements with an ID equal to `"mesaj_baslik"`, in the HTML snippet that you have provided. In fact this particular string is nowhere to be found in the HTML.

So even if the method was correct, this `ie.Document.getElementById("mesaj_baslik")`, would return `Nothing`.

Secondly, although your usage of the method  `ie.document.getElementsByName()` is correct, there is no element with a Name attribute being equal to `"formlar_mesajyaz"`, in the HTML snippet you have provided.

In fact this string seems to be a Class name rather than anything else. In this case you would have to use this method: `ie.document.getElementsByClassName()`.

Now, from the info you have provided, the best I can do is assume that, what you want to do is enter some text in the `textArea` element. To do that, you can use the element's ID like so:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("mesaj_icerik").Value = "TEST"
```

Comment: When I use these codes, it doesn't write anything in that field. excel did not give error warning.

Comment: Passed to the following code without writing anything.  

ieDocument.getElementById("mesaj_icerik").Value = "TEST" <--- Dont  write and excel did not give error warning  

  ie.document.getElementsByName("mesaj_baslik").Item(0).Value = Cells(i, 1)

Comment: @Ahmet there was a typo in my answer it's `ie.document` not `ieDocument`.

Comment: Stavros Jon thanks .
I tried again.  But nothing changed: No error message ve data not transferred